# What does p.overall mean in the compareGroups package in R?

Tags: r

I have done a cluster analysis for customer data using `compareGroups`, but I don't understand what p.overall means. Does it show each that variable in clusters are the same, or the value each variable from clusters are different?

Here are some of the results

```
library(compareGroups)
data1 = data.frame(x,cluster = g1$cluster)
group<-compareGroups(cluster~.,data= data1)
clustab<-createTable(group)
clustab

--------Summary descriptives table by 'cluster'---------
```

---

```
                  1             2            3            4             5       p.overall 
                N=233          N=9          N=37         N=94         N=67
```

¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
Channel:

```
1            229 (98.3%)    1 (11.1%)    2 (5.41%)    6 (6.38%)    60 (89.6%)     <0.001     
Fresh        11236 (9863) 20696 (15256) 8817 (18414) 7815 (7349)  21120 (17473)   <0.001
Milk         2001 (1344)  37557 (20033) 16097 (7131) 7545 (3067)   6587 (3667)    <0.001
```

¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, `p.overall` simply lists the p-values for t-tests (or Mann-Whitney U tests, if your data are non-normal) performed between each of your clusters. Looking at the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/compareGroups/compareGroups.pdf) for `compareGroups`, we see that it apparently corrects for multiple comparisons when necessary.

In this case, *if you choose your significance level to be alpha = 0.05*, then your reported p-values would indicate that the groups **differ** from one another in both the "Fresh" and "Milk" variables.

This question is not really appropriate for StackOverflow, but I figured I'd help you anyway. If you have other questions about statistical analysis, try: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ouuuh... i see thank u for the answer, the reason i asked here... Because kinda difficult to get an answer there.